# string has trailing whitespaces that aren't white spaces? (i.e. strip doesn't get rid of it)

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have the following string I got from parsing some html:

"this is my string  "

If I use `.strip` or `.rstrip` the string remains the same.

However if I literally type the string `"this is my string  "` and type `.strip` then the trailing spaces get stripped.

This leads me to believe the string I obtained from parsing html is not containing trailing white spaces. So the question I have is, 1) what is trailing the string if it isn't a white space? and 2) how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unicode table contains several whitespace characters, and it is possible that all of these characters are not handle by the strip methods. If you want to use a regular expression with the [sub method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-sub), you can try this simple pattern: `/\p{Space}+\z/` or `/[[:space:]]+\z/` to trim all the blank characters on the right. *(obviously, the replacement string must be empty)*

Note: the `\s` is equivalent to `[ \t\r\n\f]` in Ruby and doesn't contain all whitespaces of the unicode table.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I found another solution. The issue was that the space was a Non Breaking Space which is not removed by strip or \s. However it is removed by [[:space:]] so I used `/[[:space:]]*\z/` to solve this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Chowza: Thanks! good to know, I will update my answer as soon as possible with this new element of information and after any researches.

Comment: +1 for taking us into space in three different ways :) (If we count the `\s` which would work in .NET, Python 3, Perl, JS, PCRE/u)